# jquery only check ratio one image on page

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I have few divs on page and I am trying to add classes to them with jQuery.
But jQuery is checking only ratio of first backround-image and adding the same class to all div's.

How to check ratio for all background-images?

Snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var image_url = $('.class1').css('background-image'),
        image;

    // Remove url() or in case of Chrome url("")
    image_url = image_url.match(/^url\("?(.+?)"?\)$/);

    if (image_url[1]) {
        image_url = image_url[1];
        image = new Image();

        // just in case it is not already loaded
        $.each(image).load(function () {
            //   alert(image.width + 'x' + image.height);
            var ratio = image.width / image.height;

            if (ratio > 1) {
                $(".class1").addClass("added_1");
            } else if (ratio < 1) {
                $(".class1").addClass("added_2");
            }
        });

        image.src = image_url;

    };
})
```

Comment: Use `this` into the `each` instead of `image`. Same for `.class1` selector. Put your `HTML` if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery's `width()` and `height()` method.

try this

```
 $.each(image, function () {
        var ratio = $(this).width()/$(this).height();

        if (ratio > 1) {
          $(".class1").addClass("added_1");
        }
        else if (ratio < 1) {
          $(".class1").addClass("added_2");
        }
   });

  image.src = image_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything inside an `$('.class1').each(function(){});`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class1').each(function(){
        var checkClass = $(this);
        var image_url = checkClass.css('background-image'),
        image;

        // Remove url() or in case of Chrome url("")
        image_url = image_url.match(/^url\("?(.+?)"?\)$/);

        if (image_url[1]) {
            image_url = image_url[1];
            image = new Image();

            // just in case it is not already loaded
                $.each(image).load(function () {
                //   alert(image.width + 'x' + image.height);
                var ratio = image.width/image.height;

                if (ratio > 1) {
                  checkClass.addClass("added_1");
                }
                else if (ratio < 1) {
                  checkClass.addClass("added_2");
                }
            });

        image.src = image_url;

        }
    });
});
```